# Limiting a linear model to 3rd level interactions in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a dataset with 14 binary variables.  I've already tested for significant single variables, but I'd like to also check for significant interactions.  However, I know that higher level interactions are unlikely to be significant and just muddle the model.  Is there anyway to run a linear model in R, but tell it to only test for interaction between a maximum of 3 variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the first 5 columns of the built-in anscombe data set:

```
lm(y1 ~ .^3, anscombe[1:5])
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y1 ~ .^3, data = anscombe[1:5])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2           x3           x4        x1:x2  
   12.81992     -2.60371           NA           NA     -0.16258      0.36279  
      x1:x3        x1:x4        x2:x3        x2:x4        x3:x4     x1:x2:x3  
         NA           NA           NA           NA           NA     -0.01345  
   x1:x2:x4     x1:x3:x4     x2:x3:x4  
         NA           NA           NA
```

Comment: I had no idea the ^3 notation was a thing.  Awesome, simple fix.

Comment: (btw, I upvoted this answer). One thing I don't understand is why there's only a single coefficient for each pairwise and triwise interaction. What does it signify? For instance `x1:x2`, `y ~ 0.36(x1) + 0.36(x2)`?

Comment: Because the columns of `anscombe` are numeric, not factor.

Answer (score 1):

A manual approach

Use `combn` to make a triplet combinations of features

```
Comb <- combn(names(iris)[1:4],3)
```

Output

```
     [,1]           [,2]           [,3]           [,4]          
[1,] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" 
[2,] "Sepal.Width"  "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Length"
[3,] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Petal.Width"  "Petal.Width"
```

Then use `as.formula` to manually define formula using combinations of 3 features

```
ans <- apply(Comb, 2, function(x) glm(as.formula(paste0("Species ~ ", paste0(x, collapse=" + "))), data=iris, family=binomial()))
ans
```

Output

```
[[1]]

Call:  glm(formula = as.formula(paste0("Species ~ ", paste0(x, collapse = " + "))), 
    family = binomial(), data = iris)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  
       71.80        -23.91        -13.51         34.95  

Degrees of Freedom: 149 Total (i.e. Null);  146 Residual
Null Deviance:      191 
Residual Deviance: 3.523e-09    AIC: 8

[[2]]

Call:  glm(formula = as.formula(paste0("Species ~ ", paste0(x, collapse = " + "))), 
    family = binomial(), data = iris)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Width  
     -25.477         6.762       -19.057        59.292  

Degrees of Freedom: 149 Total (i.e. Null);  146 Residual
Null Deviance:      191 
Residual Deviance: 4.144e-09    AIC: 8

# etc
```